# TrayIcon set tray label in Linux Gnome

Tags: java, linux, awt, trayicon

So, thanks to this post ([SWT System Tray - Linux GTK Gnome Tray icons...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345450/swt-system-tray-linux-gtk-gnome-tray-icons-with-swt-string-on-tray)), I should be able to set **title** (yes, the thread is misleading) of my application.

But now, how do I get the tray itself to match my application name?

Screenshot:

[image]

I'm running Fedora 17 with GNOME3.
I'm not using SWT, I'm using Swing and the regular AWT that comes with Java.

Comment: Maybe you can upload your Screenshot on some other ImageHosting Service and edit your question to add the link.