# Control the tooltip string for toplevel icons shown in the gnome dash

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit, gnome-shell

When running a Tcl/Tk program in gnome-shell, all toplevels created by the application add an icon to the dash. When hovering over these icons, they all pop up a tooltip saying "Toplevel", which is not very helpful.

The `wm title` and `wm iconname` commands have no effect on the displayed tooltip. Apparently the tooltip shows the toplevel's database class value. Indeed, providing a `-class` option to the `toplevel` command does affect the tooltip.

However, this has some limitations. I believe it is not customary to have white space in a class name. Also it is not possible to modify the `-class` option after the widget has been created.

Is there a better way to control the string displayed in the dash tooltip?

Comment: Can you show a minimal example of how you're creating that GUI? If I do `echo 'button .b -text "Click me" -command exit; pack .b' | wish`, then the dock icon's tooltip is "Wish" (Ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: As indicated, I'm using the toplevel command. So for example: `echo 'toplevel .t1;toplevel .t2;toplevel .t3' | wish`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324163/how-to-set-application-title-in-gnome-shell seems relevant…

Comment: Based on information at that link, I tried `wm protocol .t1 WM_CLASS Bla`. That has no effect. Not even when surrounded by `wm withdraw .t1` and `wm deiconify .t1`. So it would seem that specifying a class at creation time is the only possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the only possibility to influence the dash tooltip is through the `-class` option to the `toplevel` command.

For example:

```
toplevel .log -class "Event Log"
```

The space makes working with class bindings a bit cumbersome, but they do work.